# How to bypass the addition of headers in custom auth HttpInterceptor using HttpClient in angular?

Tags: angular

I have created a custom authentication interceptor which implements HttpInterceptor. I will be adding headers to the every request I make with httpClient.
Now I have few requests which don't need authentication headers to be added.

Below is the code of my custom interceptor for reference

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private franchiserService: FranchiserService,
              private currentMerchantService: CurrentMerchantService) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {

    console.log('Request Intercepted');

    const franchiserKey = this.franchiserService.franchiser.apiKey;
    const merchantKey = this.currentMerchantService.merchant.apiKey;

    const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.append('franchiserKey', franchiserKey).append('merchantKey', merchantKey),
      url: environment.origin + req.url
    });

    return next.handle(authReq);
  }

}
```

How I can implement custom interceptor which can do the both?

Comment: i am not sure if that is possible without some hack , as http interceptor has not been designed like that i guess

Comment: Well, test if the request is one of these few requests, add the headers if false, and don't add them if true.

Comment: @JBNizet I have 4 to 5 requests which don't require the headers, isn't implementing with if-else is crude way to do it?

Comment: crude or not, what other choice do you have?

Comment: okay. I will use if-else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can by-pass global auth headers in Angular by adding your own http handler type ***(check handler types in angular documentation here https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHandler)*** in the services that do not need to be intercepted

```
import { HttpClient, HttpBackend } from @angular/common/http;

 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private handler: httpBackend ) {
     this.http = new HttpClient(handler); // provide handler of type HttpBackend   }
```

Adding this handler of type HttpBackend will tell it to by pass all other handlers and move to the last one. Auth interception in angular usually happens in the order auth interceptors were added, finally ending at the HttpBackend. Adding it directly like this skips all interception

Comment: This does work! But I'm not sure if instanciating HttpClient is the right thing to do here. I think a better way would be following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53679340/1707589