# how to provide interceptor optionally

Tags: angular

I have two interceptors -- `MainInterceptor` and `OptionalInterceptor`.

```
export const httpInterceptorProviders = [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MainInterceptor, multi: true }, 
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: OptionalInterceptor, multi: true }
];
```

and I provide them in `app.module`:

```
providers: [
    ...
    httpInterceptorProviders
]
```

The logic inside `OptionalInterceptor` should be executed only in specific conditions (depending on the value of a cookie). I have a service `ConfigService` that reads the cookie and knows the condition.
Right now I inject this service in `OptionalInterceptor` and execute the logic or not depending on service state.

However the cookie is available (or not) at load time, hence it feels it would be cleaner not to load the `OptionalInterceptor` at all.

I could create `NoopInterceptor` and do something like:

```
export const httpInterceptorProviders = [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MainInterceptor, multi: true }, 
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useFactory: (srv: ConfigService) => srv.optional ? OptionalInterceptor: NoopInterceptor, multi: true, deps: [ConfigService] }
];
```

but it does not feel any better.
Finally I could define `httpInterceptorProviders` as a factory:

```
export const httpInterceptorProviders = (srv: ConfigService) => {...}
```

in this case I do not see how can I inject the service in module:

```
httpInterceptorProviders(injectedService)
```

or

```
{provide: ???, useFactory: httpInterceptorProviders, deps:[ConfigService]}
```

Well there is also an approach from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53679340/1195028). It provides different HttpClient instances injected with different interceptors, but for a simple case this solution looks worse than the problem. It strictly gets the job done, but with even less elegance than doing ifs to skip the logic or creating a `NoopInterceptor`.

(edit) Just to clarify: why I prefer forcing to load interceptors conditionally instead of applying the condition in the interceptor code? I regard applying condition during the loading of the interceptor to be more clear and maintainable. In order to avoid questions like "why our interceptor is not working, is it broken?" and going to the interceptor code for answer.

Comment: You cannot conditionally apply HttpInterceptors in angular. I would suggest registering your optional Http Interceptor and then putting your conditional logic within the interceptor opposed to hacking your way through conditional injection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add HttpClient Interceptors conditionally in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781379/how-to-add-httpclient-interceptors-conditionally-in-angular)

Comment: @mwilson - as I already mentioned, I currently have my conditional code in interceptor. Just wanted to improve if possible. The answer you link to is similar to what I link to. Rather complex and solves a different problem - different interceptors for different services. Does not really help with my situation. IMO

Comment: A good question with [several examples out there on ignoring interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469349/how-to-make-an-angular-module-to-ignore-http-interceptor-added-in-a-core-module). While interesting, most of the solutions cross the line from "elegant" into "over-engineered" IMO. Seeing "if (cookie) { do this }" in an interceptor is way more maintainable than having to trace chains of wacky factories, injections and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by coding two acceptable versions. One works by directly retrieving the cookie (no point on injecting the service for this trivial task):

```
export const mainHttpInterceptorProviders = [...];
export const httpInterceptorProvidersWithOptional = [
    ...mainHttpInterceptorProviders,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: OptionalInterceptor, multi: true }
];
export const getHttpInterceptorProviders = () => {
    return getCookie(cookieOptional) ? httpInterceptorProvidersWithOptional : mainHttpInterceptorProviders;
}
```

and in module:

```
providers: [
    ...
    getHttpInterceptorProviders()
]
```

The other option is by using `NoopInterceptor` and `useFactory`. `NoopInterceptor` explicitly says that interceptor is just a placeholder and does no work. I already mentioned this option in my question and after evaluating the options decided to go with it:

```
export class NoopInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   return next.handle(req);
 }
}
export const httpInterceptorProviders = [ 
    ...mainHttpInterceptorProviders,
    { 
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
      useFactory: (srv: ConfigService) => srv.optional ? new OptionalInterceptor(): new NoopInterceptor(), 
      multi: true, deps: [ConfigService]
    }
];
```